# Does Javascript handle integer overflow and underflow? and if yes how ?

Tags: javascript

i want to analyse some program written in javascrpt by TAjS tool . so i want to answer the following question :

Does Javascript handle integer overflow and underflow? If yes, how?

Comment: Basicly no, since JS has only floating point number type.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript Number does have a maximum (defined by [`Number.MAX_VALUE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE)).

**From experimentation**: The following code illustrates how Javascript (at least in Chrome console) handles overflow:

```
var i = Number.MAX_VALUE *2;
console.log(i);

>> Infinity
```

Underflow doesn't appear to "work" though:

```
var i = Number.MIN_VALUE - Number.MAX_VALUE;
console.log(i);

>> -1.7976931348623157e+308
```